# como puedo instalar npm install -g exp to install en mi proyecto?

Tags: android, ios, npm, react-native

estoy tratando de instalar esta dependencia para poder generar el apk de mi proyecto pero no se instala, dura un rato cargando y al final me muestra un error:

```
npm ERR! Expected: e6c37c74c2ede6c32f04b13d30383e10255908d3, npm ERR! 
Actual: 6bb5a42aa7d85b993db244095018c2a71391adef npm ERR! From: 
registry.npmjs.org/@expo/ngrok/-/ngrok-2.3.0.tgz`
```

yo he estado utilizando expo para poder probar mi aplicacion con este emulador enotnces no me queda claro si ya esta incorporado en mi proyecto ya que mi package.json en la parte de dependencias me muestra `"expo": "^22.0.2"`, pero en la consola al escribir `exp start` me dice que no reconoce `'exp'`

Comment: deberias de buscar que version tienes instalada en tu maquina, y con cual version es valida en tu npm

Comment: si lo que quieres es generar el apk se pude hacer de manera muy sencilla siguiendo las instrucciones de la documentacion
[https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html)

Comment: hey Leandro, ¿pudiste hacerlo funcionar?